# Can ubuntu be used to print from school networked printers?

Tags: wireless, networking, printing

I have looked through some questions but haven't found any direct answers- I am considering a Chromebook because of the cheap price, but not being able to connect to my school's networked printers would be a deal breaker. I read that ubuntu can be used on Chromebooks, but can it be used to print from printers on a network?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and we even have a [document](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu) on the ubuntu.com website. From the link:

**[Overview](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu#Overview)**

Ubuntu supports printer sharing over networks, so you can print from your Ubuntu machine, your Windows machine, etc, to another Ubuntu or Windows machine that has a printer attached (ie a "Ubuntu print server" or "Windows print server").

**[Background](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu#Background)**

Ubuntu uses the Common UNIX Printing System ("CUPS") to handle printing. CUPS uses the Internet Printing Protocol ("IPP") as the basis for managing print jobs and queues. Other protocols are also supported (LPD, SMB, AppSocket a.k.a. JetDirect), some with reduced functionality.

CUPS printer configuration and management is handled by the Printer Admin utility launched from the Gnome menu - System -> Administration -> Printing (If the menu item does not exist you need to add system-config-printer to the menu). Also IPP provides web services so after you have configured CUPS appropriately, you can access the printers and jobs via your web browser.

When a locally attached printer is defined, eg using the Printer Admin utility, that printer is automatically published from this "print server" host to the network, depending on the server directives in the CUPS configuration file. A remote Ubuntu "client" host can then be able to see and use the printer attached to the server. The network printer automatically appears in the client's Printer Admin utility. It simply pops up if CUPS is up and configured correctly and disappears if you stop CUPS at either the Print Server or your local machine.

[More about this in the link](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu).

---

**Dash->Printers**

[image]

In the "printer set up dialog" there is a server->settings option at the top where you can set for the system to scan for network printers. In 14.04 it looks like this:

[image]

"Publish shared printers connected to this server" needs to be selected and when searching for printers it will also scan for network printers. After that is a matter of selecting and adding the printers found.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spare laptop o PC perhaps you could install Ubuntu on them and see if you can print. I can add my windows networked HP printer driver to my Ubuntu laptop and print. That is using a wireless connection to my router which then passes the request to the printer PC. As I say, it would be best if you could test this before you buy a Chromebook Laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the IP of the printer, you might also be able to add the printer via that. Also via the "add printer" dialogue.